# Vue instance works when corresponding id to el option doesn't exist

Tags: vue.js

I am using Vue via cdn.

The webpage I'm working on is using some weird proprietary syntax
which forced me not to assign id attribute to certain HTML elements.
In order to make the webpage work as it's supposed to, I removed the id attribute from the HTML element.

Then strangely it worked. I was curious so tested by making a temporary vue instance without an HTML element like below,

```js
let testVUe = new Vue({
  el: "#test", // there's no HTML element with "test" id
  mounted() {
    console.log("will this be called?", this.$el);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
```

and the mounted function was called.

Is this an expected behavior? if so, could someone explain why?

[edit]
a few minutes later, the code didn't work as expected..strange
so I added a temporary el element just for the sake of testing.

this way it works, but throws an warning.

Comment: I made your code into a runnable snippet and it does not log anything to the console. Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also, the `el` parameter does not need to be an ID. Any valid CSS selector is fine. See https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#el

Comment: @Phil thanks for the doc link! was mindlessly looking at the guide page which was the first search result lol. being able to use css selector is very awesome! does that mean that I get to assign multiple vue instances to each and every respected doms? like repeated doms via v-for?

Comment: I updated the snippet to include whatever element Vue is mounted to. As you can see, it seems to have created a `<div>`

Comment: @Phil thats kinda amazing. I'm going to test this myself and more. thank you for the insight!